# Screen brightness maximum too low on Thinkpad X300 Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, brightness, thinkpad

I can adjust the brightness of my display with the keys without problems, however the maximum brightness is much dimmer than it was in windows. Is it possible to change the maximum brightness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to check/possibly fix this is with another program, xbacklight.

In terminal type:

```
sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

then type:

```
xbacklight -set 50
```

50 is the brightness range (0 to 100).

You can increase/decrease brightness with:

```
xbacklight -inc 5
```

Decrease 5%:

```
xbacklight -dec 5
```

If this does not enable you to increase past your previous max, then it is the hardware, and maybe even just the color pallet you have set.

Comment: Thanks; I think it is the hardware. All of the above worked, but not past the maximum